# How to change qt5 color scheme permanently?

Tags: linux, gnome, themes, qt

I am trying to fix some colors in qt5 applications. I'm using a dark theme and some of the text colors are not bright enough on the dark background.

However, I am very confused about how to achieve this. I have Kvantum Manager and qt5ct installed, but I am not sure which one does exactly what. I was able to switch to a different theme with Kvantum Manager and change the look the qt application, but I couldn't figure out how to change specific font colors.

With the help of this [article](https://www.pcsuggest.com/qt5ct-change-qt5-application-style/), I was able to change the text color (in my case by choosing a custom palette, cloning a color scheme and editing the "Less dark" color). But it worked only if I started the qt application with

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct <application>
```

Unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to make the changes permanent.
Both adding `export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct` to `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/101-qt` and `~/.xinitrc` did not work.

(If I change an Icon Theme with qt5ct, the changes are permanent.)

**What is the proper way to change the color scheme or theme, and make the changes permanent?**

**Edit:**

Is there a way to check what theme/color scheme qt5 is loading? Or if `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct` is really applied?

---

Config: Arch Linux (Manjaro Gnome)

Comment: In terminal type `echo ${QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME}`. If it returns `qt5ct` then the variable is set. Also, try to put `export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME="qt5ct"` in `.profile` file or `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Thanks, for the comment. The issue in the application is not there anymore, therefore I don't want to tinker with it at the moment. Just don't want it to get worse again